# How to use video element or html content as a face texture in three.js?

Tags: youtube, three.js, render-to-texture

I am looking to use a video texture for a face in three.js. I know this is fairly easy to do if you have the video data. But what would I do if I only have the element it is playing from?

For example: How would I play a youtube video and copy the video or player onto a face in three.js?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an example of integrating Three.js and YouTube videos at

http://threejs.org/examples/css3d_youtube.html#cats

and examples of including general HTML elements (using CSS3D) at

http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2013/04/30/closing-the-gap-between-html-and-webgl/ 
and http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/CSS3D.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: The legendary @LeeStemkoski

Comment: Hello Stemkoski, your http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/CSS3D.html may be my last bet, but whenever I do `rendererCss.domElement.appendChild(rendererGl.domElement)`, the `rendererCss` is just behind of `rendererGl` and can't be seen until I manually delete the `rendererGl.domElement` using the Developer Tools' Elements.

I'm having a hard time making an embedded `iframe` and `rendererGl` result's objects interactable on each other, you might look https://discourse.threejs.org/t/using-same-scene-with-2-renderers-overlapping-objects/2975/9?u=5ervant if you have time. Thanks! :)